# Can't find /system partition in EDL mode

Tags: partitions, android-11

I have a OnePlus Nord N10 with Android 11. I want to create a physical image of the /system partition, mount it on my computer and browse it's filesystem. I've read that FBE only encrypts the "userdata" partition so this should be possible.

I have a locked bootloader therefore I use the EDL mode of the device to create a dump. I'm able to put my device into EDL mode and use [edl](https://github.com/bkerler/edl) to print the device's partition table. However I don't see a "system" partition that I could dump. Here is the command output: https://pastebin.com/raw/QUF6ZgEf

Where is the "system" partition with the Android system files?

Comment: If your device has a system partition I would expect it to be the second largest (largest is user data). Not sure why you want to dump system partition, extracting it from a downloaded firmware image is usually easier. BTW are you sure your phone has a system partition? The partition and folder layout has changed so modern device don't have a system partition anymore, but I don't know if Android 11 already uses the new layout.